# Hosting website through VPN not working

Tags: vpn, webserver, nat

I would like to host my own small website from home. However, my ISP NATs all the customers, making that impossible.

I Googled the problem and found answers suggesting to use a VPN tunnel.

I set up the Windscribe VPN on the server and tried to connect to it from its public IP address, but I was unsuccessful. The connection attempt was made with another machine on a separate network.

Other people seem to have had success with this. What am I missing?

Comment: It is likely that the ISP NAT's also prevent the VPN to work. VPN traffic needs to go over certain ports, just like a webserver does. You can see if your ISP allows certain ports to be open, and simply setup your webserver to work on that port instead. That does mean your url changes to http://ip:port rather than just http://ip.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't heard of that before, I'll look into it.

Comment: Also the VPN works to load web pages, etc. And wouldn't the NAT, even if a port was open, not know which IP to send the inbound request to?

Comment: @robinCTS Thanks so much for making my question better!